# Remind yourself to take bags to a market

Tags: time-management

Most of my grocery shopping is online but I often like to go to special small supermarkets which have yet to find good arrangements for online marketing, or to fruit and vegetable bazzars.

In these occasions I quite often forget to take non-nylon bags with me (reusable fiber bags) which I want to always take to such places and which are anyway mandatory by law where I reside.

I have an Android operated smartphone (OnePlus 6) and I desire a FOSS-Gratis small app that will remind me "take bags!" each time I leave a residence (at least on chosen days and/or times of the week).

What will you recommend?

Comment: I would recommend forgetting about an app. Seriously. Personally, I leave a single bag hanging out of the pocket of my coat. I f I leave, to not go shopping, I leave it on the coat-hanger, where I will see it when I get back. If I am shopping, it reminds me to take more bags. If you don't wear a hat, I am sure that you can think of something similar. E.g I don't sit around the house with my wallet in my pocket, so I could put a bag with my wallet. I have a table at the front door for keys, loose coins, etc I could leave a bag there, or just a post-it.

Comment: I _could_ code such an app, but how would it know that you are leaving your house?  I could detect loss of home WiFi, but you would have locked your door and been half way down the street by the time that happens. I could attach an ESP32 to your door-frame (adding mains power) and code that to trigger an app that I coded for your 'phone. But, seriously, if you are looking for 'phone app to solve this problem, you might want to do some thinking about your relationship with your'phone. Our [LifeHackers](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/) site can help with a non-phone related solution